# Using if with DATE error

Tags: php, if-statement

Where I went wrong? I make its code, but not work, please help me anybody, thankyu!

```
<?php
$tm = date("H");
$td = date("W");
if ($td != "0" and ($tm >= "8" and $tm <= "22")){
// button
?>
<html...>
<?php ) ?>
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: What IS wrong, exactly? What do you expect this code to do that it does  not?

Answer (score 1):

At the last line you have bad brace, there has to be `}` instead of `)`.

```
<?php
$tm = date("H");
$td = date("W");
if ($td != 0 and ($tm >= 8 and $tm <= 22)) {
// button
?>
<html...>
<?php } ?>
      ^^
```

As a bonus I've removed quotes around number on 4th line.